# How can I automatically refresh a partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a simple view:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Administration
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">   
    <h2>Indexer stats</h2>


    <div id="Stats">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("IndexerStats", CmsModels.Utilities.BackgroundIndexer.Default); %>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

How can I automatically refresh the Partial View "IndexStats" every 10 seconds?

I have found [this code](http://blogs.msdn.com/miah/archive/2008/11/16/extending-mvc-auto-refreshing-a-partial-view-using-ajax.aspx), but it doesn't compile with my version of MVC (2 RC).

Comment: What happens with that code? Why doesn't it work? What errors? I don't know "Sys.Mvc.MvcHelpers", but assuming it works, skimming the code it looks functional.

Comment: It doesn't compile, giving the following errors:


Error 45 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.UrlHelper(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext)' has some invalid arguments D:\dev\dotnet\Projects\CmsWeb\CmsWeb\Utilities\HtmlUtilities.cs 98 32 CmsWeb


Error 46 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext' to 'System.Web.Routing.RequestContext' D:\dev\dotnet\Projects\CmsWeb\CmsWeb\Utilities\HtmlUtilities.cs 98 46 CmsWeb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Damn it, you spend ages looking for an answer, ask the question and then find the answer imediately afterwards.

Revised code is:

### Indexer stats

```
    <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>         
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            setInterval(function() {
            $.get('<%=Url.Action("IndexerStats")%>', {}, function(view) {
            $("div#IndexerStats").html(view);
                })
            }, 5000);
        }); </script>    

            <div id="IndexerStats">
                <% Html.RenderPartial("IndexerStats"); %>
            </div>
</asp:Content>
```

However I am open to better ideas, or Html helpers.